# Accessing querystring in ASP.NET MVC6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to access query string parameters in my ASP.NET MVC6 applications. But it seems unlike MVC5 and web forms, QueryString doesn't have any indexer and I can't say something like:

```
string s = Request.QueryString["key1"] //gives error
```

So, my question is - how do I access query string parameters in MVC6?

Surprisingly `Request.Forms` collection works as expected (as in MVC5 or web forms).

Thank you.

Comment: You are not supposed to use QueryString or Form in MVC, instead you should have parameter in your controller that will automatically bind to the values.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Getting query with an indexer is supported.

See MVC code test here - https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/e0b8532735997c439e11fff68dd342d5af59f05f/test/WebSites/ControllersFromServicesClassLibrary/QueryValueService.cs

```
context.Request.Query["value"];
```

Also note that in MVC 6 you can model bind directly from query by using the [FromQuery] attribute.

```
public IActionResult ActionMethod([FromQuery]string key1)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: `[FromQuery]` is what I was missing

Comment: This is actually a learning moment.  I had no idea [FromQuery] even existed.  It doesn't seem to be well documented.  There is also a [FromHeader] and [FromForm] among others.  You can even write custom binders, as well.

Answer (score 17):

> So, my question is - how do I access query string parameters in MVC6?

You can use `Request.Query` which is new addition in ASPNET 5.

```
 var queryStrings = Request.Query;
```

The URL I am going to try was - `http://localhost:12048/Home/Index?p=123&q=456`
And you can get All Keys using -

```
queryStrings.Keys
```

[image]

And then you can get the values by iterating keys -

```
 var qsList = new List<string>();
 foreach(var key in queryStrings.Keys)
 {
      qsList.Add(queryStrings[key]);
 }
```

[image]